# Properly implementing runWithParams() in Yii

Tags: php, yii

If you look under #3 in this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller it gives you a way to organize all of your controller functions into individual php files.

To do this you have to have each php file contain a class that extends CAction.  Each class must have its running code inside of the function run().

This is my UserController.php file

```
public function actions()
{
    $FOLDER = '.User';
    $PROJECT_ROOT = 'application.controllers' . $FOLDER;

    return array (
        'list' => $PROJECT_ROOT . 'ListAction',
);
```

}

In the application that I am writing I need to pass variables to specific Actions.

Yii implemented runWithParams($params) in Yii 1.7 to allow this to happen.  However, when I call write in the (for example) DeleteAction.php file runWithParams($params) instead of run() and our front end calls post/delete/?params=45 instead of run()  I get an error that says "could not find run() in file DeleteAction.php

```
class ListAction extends CAction
{
public function runWithParam($id)
{
    SiteController::actionLoggedin();
    $id = addslashes($id);
}
```

Which means that I need run()...but I can't pass parameters into run(). I need runWithParams($params).

In the documentation for the function runWithParams($params)
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAction#runWithParams-detail

it says

```
    Runs the action with the supplied request parameters. This method is internally called by CController::runAction().
```

I am confused what this means?  I don't understand how I can implement this successfully.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you are trying to do? The question is confusing, thanks.

Comment: I edited the post to make it a proper question and not just a jumbled blurb.  Take a look if you get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to implement `run()` in a CAction class.

You will automatically have access to the $_GET params, of course, like you would in your action normally:

```
class ListAction extends CAction {
  public function run() {
    $id = $_GET['id']; // $_POST works too
    $model = Model::model()->findbyPk($id);
    // render your view next, whatever
  }
}
```

If you want to pass in additional constants to the CAction from the Controller, you can do it like this:

In your action setup in your Controller:

```
public function actions() {
  return array(
    'userSearch'=>array(
      'class'=>'application.controllers.User.ListAction', // path alias to your action
      'model'=>'User',
      'otherVariable'=>'something here',
  ));
}
```

Then in your CAction:

```
class ListAction extends CAction {
  public $modelName;
  public $otherVariable;
  public function run() {
    $this->modelName; //  'User' - passed in from the calling Controller
    $this->otherVariable; //  'something here' - passed in from the calling Controller
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what other parameters you might want to pass in to your action, but that should cover it. I hope that helps!

Update:

This question has made me look at the code in more depth, and this is actually all to do with a feature of Yii which I did not know about. If you declare a parameter on your action (i.e. `function actionTest($param)`), then Yii will parse the $_GET parameters of a request and call the Action with that parameter passed in to the function. So you don't have to get the $_GET parameter yourself. Like so:

```
http://example.com/mycontroller/myaction?param1=test

function actionMyaction($param1) { // in a CAction, it would be run($param1)
  echo '$_GET parameter param1 set to '.$param1; // will echo "test"
}
```

The way this is implemented is:

1. In `runAction()` CController gets the $_GET parameters (if there are any) with `getActionParams()`
2. `runAction()` passes these parameters into `runWithParams()`
3. `runWithParams()` uses PHP Reflection to see if the action method has parameters (e.g. `$param1`)

   1. If there are parameters, it calls `runWithParamsInternal()` with the $_GET parameters

      1. `runWithParamsInternal()` calls the `run()` method with the $_GET parameters (e.g. `run($param1)`)
   2. Otherwise it just calls `run()` without any parameters

It's totally optional to use this, you can still access the $_GET parameters like normal in your action without. Basically, this just enforces required $_GET parameters. If your action needs a parameter but there are not $_GET parameters in the request URL, Yii returns an "Error 400" from `invalidActionParams()`. It saves you the burden of checking `isset($_GET)` in your action, which is kind of cool.

Comment: That's it sir.  I went in expecting runWithParams() to be something that could be used as a substitution for run().  And the extra part with the models and other variables is something i was not aware of.  Thank you sir, +++++!

Comment: I thought about this all day, and while I do agree that it is a way to implement runWithParams, it seems like I shouldn't have to call it in run() because why bother even having runWithParams?  If you are going to call run(), gather the variables from post, get, session(or whatever) and call runWithParams you could just as easily run you own function in run() and totally ignore runWithParams($p).  It seems like there is something deeper here that prevents the need to execute run() first.

Comment: I *Think* I figured this out.  I think you just call CController::runAction() INSIDE run and THAT runs runWithParams().  Which would save you the task of gather the variables.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation of what `runWithParams()` really does and how it works. I hope that clarifies. You should _never_ call `runWithParams()`, the controller does that, and `runWithParams()` calls _your_ `run()` method.

Comment: Thanks Thaddeus, I wasn't disagreeing with you on purpose. (if that makes any sense at all).  Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if my _italics_ seemed mean spirited, I just wanted to emphasize a couple points. Thanks for this question, I learned a lot trying to answer it! Cheers

Comment: Didn't seem mean sprited at all.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From the same Yii guide you point in your description:

> Starting from version 1.1.7, automatic parameter binding also works
>   for class-based actions. When the run() method of an action class is
>   defined with some parameters, they will be populated with the
>   corresponding named request parameter values. For example,

```
class UpdateAction extends CAction
{
    public function run($id)
    {
        // $id will be populated with $_GET['id']
    }
}
```

As easy as that. Define in run() all the parameters you need.

Of course you can always get the by $_GET['key'] or by Yii::app()->request->getQuery('key')

In case you add them in run, know that if you are not always going to pass all the parameters you can set default values otherwise you'll get errors.

Example:

```
public function run($id, $other_param='default_value')
```